# MongoDB Cursor has no method 'next'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

These work fine:

```
myCollection.find();
myCollection.findOne();
```

This does not:

```
           myCollection.find().next();
                               ^
TypeError: Object #<Cursor> has no method 'next'
```

But documentation says:

> cursor.next()
>
> Returns:
>   The next document in the cursor returned by the db.collection.find() method.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is `myCollection` (how did you create it)? What mongodb driver do you use? Which version? Could you provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: There's a `nextObject` on the cursor in the MongoDB Node.JS driver: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#nextobject, but no `next`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While related, the [JavaScript Methods in MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/method/) are not the same as those in the [native driver for Node.js](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/).

The former, including [`cursor.next()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/method/cursor.next/), make up MongoDB's own API and are similar to SQL commands in relational databases. Use these when connected through the [`mongo` shell](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/mongo/).

The equivalent of `cursor.next()` within the Node.js driver API is [`cursor.nextObject()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#nextobject).

Comment: `cursor.nextObject()` is deprecated now. What do?

Comment: @HarryMoreno With 2.0 of the native driver, cursor's now have a [`cursor.next()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/AggregationCursor.html#next), matching the shell API.

Answer (score 2):

Just to note that [cursor.next()](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/cursor.js.html#line327) replaces nextObject() in [2.0](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api-docs/) and is available.